# How to convert Standarized Mean Difference to OR in skewed data?

Tags: meta-analysis, skewness, odds-ratio, lognormal-distribution

There are many methods to convert Standarized Mean Differences to Odds Ratios for meta-analysis (ln(OR) = -1.8 SMD), but none that i have found really deals with skewed summary data. **Do you think i should log-transformed the summary statistics first?** Should I compare this OR with OR of binary data?

- by summary statistics I mean raw arithmetic mean and SD
- Are you aware of any work that has done something similar?

Comment: for interested people: I decided i m going to use (ln(OR) = -1.8 SMD), by first log-transforming summary statistics  (see  https://doi-org.uchile.idm.oclc.org/10.1002/sim.4298). ALthough it seems that if you have many many studies to include Central limit theory should pull you through without the need of any log-transformation whatsoever